# Hide View in @react-pdf/renderer

Tags: html, reactjs, pdf, text, react-pdfrenderer

If I want to hide a text on the last page of the pdf we do this:

```
<Text
   style={styles.paragraph}
   render={({ pageNumber, totalPages }) =>
   pageNumber === totalPages ? '' : 'Show this text'
   }
 />
```

I am trying to hide a view on the last page, let's suppose this is the View I want to hide on the last page

```
<View
   style={styles.paragraph}
   render={({ pageNumber, totalPages }) =>
   pageNumber === totalPages ? '' : 'Show this text'
   }
 />
```

But it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you not wrap the condition above the `View`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
{  pageNumber !== totalPages ?(
<View
   style={styles.paragraph}
   render={({ pageNumber, totalPages }) =>{ Your content here}
   }
 />
):null}
```

Comment: I think it will not work render is not working in View.